# Spring MVC ajax post text data

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I have a form:

```
 <form name="employeeForm" method="post">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="GridOne">
            <tr>
               <td>First Name</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" onchange="FirstNameAjaxCall(event);"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Last Name</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Email</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="madeAjaxCall(event);"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
```

//====================================================

and my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajaxExample", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView firstnameAjaxTest(@RequestParam(value="text") String text) {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        System.out.println(text);
        modelAndView.setViewName("ajaxExample");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

//===============================================

and script

```
function FirstNameAjaxCall(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var text = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
       alert(text);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/ajaxExample",
            cache: false, 
            dataType: 'text',   
            data:{
                text:text
            },
            success: function(){
                alert('Done');
            },
            error: function(){      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
       });
       return false;

      return false;
     }
```

And request return msg: Error while request..
I doesn understand why.
Please help me

Comment: First you are sending json not a parameter, second it doesn't make sense to return a `ModelAndView` from a `@ResponseBody` annotated method.

Comment: Rewrite ajax request as: add
             dataType: 'json',   
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
     now my controller return String. And i have error: can not make cors request

Comment: Read my comment. It isn't about your Ajax call it is about your controller. You are still sending JSON as a body NOT as a parameter.

Comment: I change my conroller: add @RequestMapping(value="/sokolajaxtest", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")  and return String "{\"text\":\"success\"}". U that mean? Now ajax return me  SUCCESS:  /error/access-denied

Comment: Apparently you have security enabled and you aren't including any security related information in your request.

Comment: Acces denied - this problem is connected with cros origin. For controller was added annotation @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080"). Also was created Global CORS Configuration (use this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_cors_support.htm). But it is doesnt help me. But i understand tha the problem in server side